# Custom select on react , filtering list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making custom dropdown https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-driscoll-cjkcj . I want when user pick element from dropdown do not display that item in list again. 
Here how it looks when I click on select first time

[image]

then when I pick that item and opening dropdown again that element shows in list

[image]

I want to remove it from that list , do not display it again. Check https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-driscoll-cjkcj for full code

```
 <DropdownContentUI isOpen={isOpen}>
        {arrayOfSvg.map((item, idx) => {
          const { svg } = item;
          return (
             <DropdownArrowsWrapperUI key={idx} onClick={() => SelectIcon(idx)}>
              {svg}
            </DropdownArrowsWrapperUI>
          );
        })}
      </DropdownContentUI>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DropdownContentUI isOpen={isOpen}>
    {arrayOfSvg.map((item, idx) => {
      const { svg } = item;
      if(isSelected != idx){
        return (
          <DropdownArrowsWrapperUI key={idx} onClick={() => SelectIcon(idx)}>
            {svg}
          </DropdownArrowsWrapperUI>
        );
      }
    })}
  </DropdownContentUI>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter the list of options before mapping through it.

```
<DropdownContentUI isOpen={isOpen}>
        {arrayOfSvg
          .filter((item, idx) => idx !== isSelected)
          .map((item, idx) => {
            const { svg } = item;
            return (
              <DropdownArrowsWrapperUI
                key={idx}
                onClick={() => SelectIcon(idx)}
              >
                {svg}
              </DropdownArrowsWrapperUI>
            );
          })}
      </DropdownContentUI>
```